# Запуск java класс из командной строки

Tags: java, cmd

У меня есть готовый проект написанный в NetBeans с 3-мя классами. Как мне скомпилировать и запустить из командной строки все это? 
к примеру есть файлы

```
one.java
two.java
three.java

one.class
two.class
three.class
```

Все это хранится в С:\User\Name\ от сюда же я и компилирую.
При компиляции главного класса, выдает много ошибок по типу "не вижу элементов других классов". Главный класс One.

Comment: Судя по наличию class-файлов, программа уже скомпилирована. Пакет используется?

Comment: в каждом классе присутствует package test1;

Comment: Тогда классы надо положить в подкаталог test1 и выполнить команду `java -cp . test1.One`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!